# Installing TexLive on headless Debian Wheezy machine

Tags: debian, xorg, latex, debian-wheezy

I want to install TexLive on a headless machine running Debian Wheezy (X11 is not installed). However, when I run apt-get it wants to pull in X11 packages. As I access the machine via SSH, and would be viewing the compiled documents as a PDF via the web browser or over SSHFS, I feel as though install X11 is not necessary for my needs and will just be unnecessary bloat.

Is X11 actually required? Is there a way I can install TexLive (or some other Latex package) without X11?

Answer (score 2):

It probably depends on some other package that needs X11 libraries. Often IMHO too much is pulled in via recommends and suggests, I usually put this in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local :

```
APT::Install-Recommends "0";
APT::Install-Suggests "0";
```

then run aptitude interactively, select the package I want to install, and hit 'g' and check what packages are suggested/recommended (but not selected) and add any I consider to be perhaps useful additions. That cuts down on a lot.

That said, having all sorts of X11-related stuff on a system without any X11 display isn't a problem, it just takes up disk space.